# Scrape the text of a selected Drop Down item with rvest

Tags: css, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping some website using *Rselenium* and *rvest*. Therefore I am cycling through items of a drop down menu to change the javascript table.
The table name from the drop down menu should become my identifier column in the scraped table. I managed to scrape the table, but I am stuck when scraping just the one selected menu entry.
Here are some lines of the html code:

```
<select>
<option value="5823">2010/2011</option>
<option value="7094">2011/2012</option>
<option value="9024">2012/2013</option>
<option value="11976">2013/2014</option>
<option value="15388">2014/2015</option>
<option value="18336" selected="selected">2015/2016</option>
</select>
```

How do I get the html_text of the selected column? The css selector :checked doesn't work.
I tried:

```
 html_nodes("option") %>% html_attrs()
```

Which correctly gives me:

```
 [[1]]
 value 
"5823" 

[[2]]
 value 
"7094" 

[[3]]
 value 
"9024" 

[[4]]
  value 
"11976" 

[[5]]
  value 
"15388" 

[[6]]
  selected      value 
"selected"    "18336"
```

and

```
read_html(wData) %>% html_nodes("option") %>% html_text()
[1] "2010/2011" "2011/2012" "2012/2013" "2013/2014" "2014/2015" "2015/2016"
```

But I don't know how to bring the two together. I only get:

```
[1] "2015/2016"
```

Since I am then cycling through the options I need a general solution.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an `xpath` selector rather than a css selector.

```
read_html(wData) %>% html_nodes(xpath="//option[@selected]")  %>% html_text()
```

This allows you to search for attributes even when the `:checked` css pseudo class doesn't work.

Comment: Great solution.
I found another one...since I am already using RSelenium for the javascript part, I could utilize
`remDr$findElement(using = 'css', "option:checked")$getElementText()[[1]]`
from the according package.