# How to scrape text of a drop down menu using rvest?

Tags: r, rvest

I want to scrape all existing text of a few drop down menu given by [this](https://www.siviltoplum.gov.tr/illere-ve-faaliyet-alanlarina-gore-dernekler) web page. The structure is quite simple and I've also reviewed [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461079/scrape-the-text-of-a-selected-drop-down-item-with-rvest) given before but my result is zero. The code is:

```
library(rvest);library(tidyverse)

pg <- read_html("https://www.siviltoplum.gov.tr/illere-ve-faaliyet-alanlarina-gore-dernekler")

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("option") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you try to scrape from the wrong page... inspection of source reveals an iframe from another location.

```html
<iframe allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" src="https://derbis.dernekler.gov.tr/IstatistikDerneklerWeb/IlFaaliyetAlaniDernekler" style="width: 940px; height: 916px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 5px; float: left; background-color: transparent; fontColor: #ffffff; fontSize: 32px; border-size: 0px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

```
read.this <- "https://derbis.dernekler.gov.tr/IstatistikDerneklerWeb/IlFaaliyetAlaniDernekler"

library( rvest )
library( tidyverse )

pg <- read_html(read.this, encoding = "latin1")

pg %>% 
  html_nodes("option") %>% 
  html_text()


# [1] "ADANA"                       "ADIYAMAN"                    "AFYONKARAHÄ°SAR"             "AÄ\u009eRI"                 
# [5] "AKSARAY"                     "AMASYA"                      "ANKARA"                      "ANTALYA"                    
# [9] "ARDAHAN"                     "ARTVÄ°N"                     "AYDIN"                       "BALIKESÄ°R"                 
# [13] "BARTIN"                      "BATMAN"                      "BAYBURT"                     "BÄ°LECÄ°K"                  
# [17] "BÄ°NGÃ\u0096L"               "BÄ°TLÄ°S"                    "BOLU"                        "BURDUR"  
....
```